# How to get nested Javascript object when depth is unknown?

Tags: javascript, nested, javascript-objects

Suppose I have these arrays:

```
const array1 = [
   {
      data: {
         site: {
            tag: {
               name: "Bikes", 
               posts: { ... }
            }
         }
      },
      errors: {}
   },
   { ... }   
]

const array2 = [
   {
      data: {
         category: {
            name: "Cars", 
            posts: { ... }
         }
      },
      errors: {}
   },
   { ... }   
]

const array3 = [
   {
      data: {
         posts: { ... }
      },
      errors: {}
   }, 
   { ... }  
]
```

What function can I use on array 1 and 2 so that I am always left with an array shaped like array 3? How can I always extract `posts` from `data` without knowing at what position it is in the nested object?

I've tried a few things with `find` or `filter` or recursive functions but I'm just no good at this, sorry. Hope somebody can help!

Comment: Will there be multiple `posts` entry in `data`? e.g. `data:{site:{posts:{}},category:{posts:{}}}`

Comment: @Passerby Nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit deeper, I've got it working with this:

```
const result = []

const getPosts = obj => {

   if( obj?.posts ) {
      return obj.posts
   } 
        
   for( const key of Object.values( obj ) ) {
      return getPosts(key)
   }
   
}
     
array1.forEach( item => { // Also works with array2
   result.push({ 
      data: {
         posts: getPosts( item.data )
      },
      errors: item.errors 
   })
})

console.log( result ) // result will look like array3
```

Answer (score 0):

If there might be only these two structures then you can manually extract `posts` based on whether data contains the `site` field or the `category` field.

```
const extractPosts = ({data, errors})=>{
    return {
        data: {
            posts: data.site ? data.site.tag.posts : data.category.posts
        },
        errors
    }
}

const unknownStructureArray = [{
    data: {
        site: {
            tag: {
                name: "Bikes",
                posts: {
                    type: 'primary'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    errors: {}
}, {
    data: {
        category: {
            name: "Cars",
            posts: {
                type: 'secondary'
            }
        }
    },
    errors: {}
}, ];

const array3 = unknownStructureArray.map(extractPosts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a recursive approach, creating a function `findPosts()` that will walk through an object to find any posts.

We'd also create a `convertArr()` function that will map an input array to the desired shape:

```js
const array1 = [
   {
      data: {
         site: {
            tag: {
               name: "Bikes", 
               posts: { 'post1': {}, 'post2': {} }
            }
         }
      },
      errors: {}
   },
   {
      data: {
         site: {
            tag: {
               name: "Stuff", 
               posts: { 'postA': {}, 'postB': {} }
            }
         }
      },
      errors: {}
   }
]

const array2 = [
   {
      data: {
         category: {
            name: "Cars", 
            posts: { post1: 'Some post', post2: 'Another post '}
         }
      },
      errors: {}
   }
]

function findPosts(input) { 
    for(let key in input) {
        if (key === 'posts') {
            return input[key];
        } else if (input[key] && (typeof(input[key]) === 'object')) {
            let posts = findPosts(input[key]);
            if (posts) {
                return posts;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function convertArr(arr) {
    return arr.map(el => { 
        return { 
            data: { posts: findPosts(el) },
            errors: el.errors
        };
    })
}

console.log('Array1:', convertArr(array1));
console.log('Array2:', convertArr(array2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since objects in JavaScript behave like pointers, you can use a queue approach to simulate the recursive operation like @TerryLennox 's answer:

```js
function simplifyPosts(objs:{data:object,errors:object}[]):{data:{posts:any},errors:any}[] {
  let rets:{data:{posts:any},errors:any}[]=[];
  objs.forEach((obj)=>{
    let ret={
      data:{
        posts:<any>null,
      },
      errors:{...obj.errors},
    };
    let queue:any[]=[obj.data];
    while(queue.length>0){
      let pointer=queue.shift();
      if(typeof pointer!="object") continue;
      if(typeof pointer.posts=="object"){
        ret.data.posts={...pointer.posts};
      }
      Object.keys(pointer).forEach((key)=>{
        queue.push(pointer[key]);
      });
    }

    rets.push(ret);
  });
  return rets;
}
```

[Online playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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)

As shown in the playground, using this function on:

```js
const array1 = [
   {
      data: {
         site: {
            tag: {
               name: "Bikes", 
               posts: { 
                 root:"array1[0]",
                }
            }
         }
      },
      errors: {}
   },
   {
     data: {
       a: {
         b: {
           c: {
             name: "Aria",
             posts: {
               root:"array1[1]",
             }
           }
         }
       }
     },
     errors: {}
   }
];

const array2 = [
   {
      data: {
         category: {
            name: "Cars", 
            posts: {
              root: "array2[0]",
            }
         }
      },
      errors: {},
   },
   {
     data: {
       a: {
         b: {
           name: "Eve",
           posts: {
             root: "array2[1]",
           }
         }
       }
     },
     errors: {},
   }   
];

console.log(simplifyPosts(array1));
console.log(simplifyPosts(array2));
```

outputs:

```
[{
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "root": "array1[0]"
    }
  },
  "errors": {}
}, {
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "root": "array1[1]"
    }
  },
  "errors": {}
}] 
[{
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "root": "array2[0]"
    }
  },
  "errors": {}
}, {
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "root": "array2[1]"
    }
  },
  "errors": {}
}]
```